# What's your view about Msn news?

Tags: news

I am developing a news website.While searching through top news based website like Google News,BBC,CNN and ... , I found that [MSN](http://www.msn.com/en-us) has better UX and UI.
What's your idea about [MSN](http://www.msn.com/en-us) ?

Comment: What if i could understand why i got downvotes :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSN is just a scraper. They develop no real news reporting or investigating of their own. They also will use Bing, not to help you find news stories, but to boost Bing's numbers to make it appear as if people will use it over Google search.

But I guess your real question is about their UX/UI.

It's clutter at its finest, mixed with pop news and advertising. A wall of text, glitter and mini-explosions to keep the uneducated entertained.

This is no different than you would find with most television "news" web sites and TV "news" in general. If you're site is one of these, then MSN isn't a bad layout to follow. If you want to be serious about news, you might look into doing the same layout but get rid of the cruft. Something like reuters.com as an example. Even then, it's a little crowded.

I'm sure there are better, like npr.org, but I haven't looked.

Comment: Thanks. Ignoring contents , what is your given point to the ux (from 10) ?

Comment: @AliN11 My third paragraph.